# How to use nested for loop with if else in the code to make it smaller

Tags: matlab, for-loop, nested

I want to reduce the size of the Code in order to avoid Manual copy paste. Therefore i want to use nested for loop or while loop for the following code

```matlab
function [MXB_01,MXB_02,MXB_03,MXB_04,MXB_05] = fcn(time)
MXB_01=0; 
MXB_02=0;   
MXB_03=0;   
MXB_04=0;   
MXB_05=0;
for j = 1:100
    if ((time >= j*0.001+0.1*0) && (time < j*0.001 + 0.001 + 0.1*0))
        MXB_01 = j*1;
    elseif ((time >= j*0.001+0.1*1) && (time < j*0.001 + 0.001 + 0.1*1))
        MXB_02 = j*1;
    elseif ((time >= j*0.001+0.1*2) && (time < j*0.001 + 0.001 + 0.1*2))
        MXB_03 = j*1;
    elseif ((time >= j*0.001+0.1*3) && (time < j*0.001 + 0.001 + 0.1*3))
        MXB_04 = j*1;
    elseif ((time >= j*0.001+0.1*4) && (time < j*0.001 + 0.001 + 0.1*4))
        MXB_05 = j*1;
    end
end
```

It goes to 100 but I have only shown 5 to illustrate the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would produce only one output variable which is a vector with all the component being zeros except one. Then to determine whether `time` is in a particular interval I would use a matrix containing those intervals (`time_slot`) and then for each interval check if `time` is in it and changing MXB accordingly.

```matlab
function [MXB] = fcn(time)
MXB  =zeros(5,1);% Vector that will hold your result instead of having hundred variables

% Creation of a dummy time slot
time_slot = 1:5;
time_slot = [time_slot' time_slot'];
time_slot(:,2) = time_slot(:,2)+1;

for j = 1:5
    if ((time >= time_slot(j,1)) && (time < time_slot(j,2)))
        MXB(j)=j;
    end
end
```

`time_slot` is

```
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   6
```

and the result of `fcn(2.5)` is

```
0
2
0
0
0
```

Comment: Creating the `time_slot` array here seems a bit overkill when `time_slot(j,:) = [j, j+1]`? Correct approach otherwise

Comment: True ! I chose not to embed it in the for loop in case the time intervals would be inconsistent needing special treatment which seems not to be the case here.

Comment: Hi Thank you Thank you very much for your quick help. 
MXB is changing to next MXB for a new time increament +1 value. I want MXB should complete 1-5 or (1-100) then move to next MXB ,it should overwrite the previous value , for example
1  ======== 1 2 3 4 5

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code, and assuming you have 100 if/else statements inside your loop, I think what you are doing is dividing the time axis into 100x100 blocks of length 0.001.

If `time` is in the first section of length 100*0.001 = 0.1, then `MXB_01` gets set to `mod(time, 0.1) / 0.001` (possibly this operation is slightly different because each of your comparisons has an offset, I kinda ignored it to understand the logic).

If `time` is in the next section of length 0.1, then `MBX_02` gets set, etc.

Which variable gets set is thus given by `ceil(time/0.1)` or something similar depending on the offset.

As the other answer suggested, you should use an array instead of 100 variables. You would end up with something similar to these two lines of code:

```
MBX = zeros(100,1);
MBX(ceil(time/0.1)) = mod(time, 0.1) / 0.001;
```